# When should we use ref in mongoose related docs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a "User" and a "Notification" Collection in my Mongo database, should I relate them using id like so :

```
const NotificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   userId: {
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     required: true
   }
});
```

or using ref :

```
userId: {
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *required* attribute is intended to specify that a field must be set.
To make a reference to another collection, you need to use the *ref* attribute:

```
userId: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  required: true
}
```

This will let you populate the User when you perform a query.